# Python loop breaks after first pass

Tags: python

I have a function containing a `while` loop that breaks after the first pass:

```
def format_sites(self, query_data):
    # Convert the list of tuples to a list of dictionaries
    self.query_data = query_data
    self.x = 0
    self.site_list = list()
    self.site_dict = dict()
    while self.x < len(self.query_data):
        self.site_dict['site_id'] = self.query_data[self.x][0]
        self.site_dict['title'] = self.query_data[self.x][1]
        self.site_dict['subtitle'] = self.query_data[self.x][2]
        self.site_dict['type'] = "menu"

        self.site_dict['options'] = self.format_devices(DBHandler(Query().query_single_site(self.query_data[self.x][0])).rows)

        self.site_list.append(self.site_dict.copy())
        self.x += 1

    return self.site_list
```

I know the line `self.site_dict['options'] = self.format_devices(DBHandler(Query().query_single_site(self.query_data[self.x][0])).rows)` is what is causing the issue because, when I remove it, everything works just fine, but I am missing the `options` key in my dictionary.

A little bit more in depth information... This function takes a list of sites from a PSQL query and formats it into the dictionary syntax I am using to build a menu. In order to get the submenu built for each "site option", I need to put my list of submenu items as the value associated with the `options` key. Now, `format_devices()` runs just fine on its own (I call this function for a menu that lists all my devices). Additionally, I copied most of the syntax for `self.format_devices(DBHandler(Query().query_single_site(self.query_data[self.x][0])).rows)` from the variable I have to call `format_sites()` in another module. The only thing I can come up with is that, somehow, maybe the `return self.device_list` at the end of `format_devices()` is what is causing the loop to end.

Please forgive any poor formatting, as I'm using this program to really learn Python.

If there are other sections of code you need to see in order to better answer the question, please let me know. It comes from quite a few different modules and I thought it might be too much excess to post.

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by reassigning values to the same keys over and over again?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I believe the intent is for the self.site_list.append(self.site_dict.copy()) line to save each version of the dict as it is generated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you think the loop only runs once?  Or, what does the function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we don't have the code for format_devices, but I have a suspicion that the issue is that format_devices iterates over some structure and modifies self.x while doing so.  If this conjecture is correct, then it explains the premature termination of the loop; when the first format_devices call is made, self.x is zero, but format_data modifies self.x and when it returns, self.x is much larger than zero.  If it is greater than the length of query_data, the loop terminates.  If this is the case, then a fix is to **change self.x to x in both format_data and format_sites**, making the loop counter function-scoped.

This is a problem in other places in this code as well - there is no reason to make an object-scoped self.query_data variable, nor self.site_list, nor self.dict_list.  These could just be query_data, site_list, and dict_list.  **When you use self.foo, you're referencing a field foo on an object, not a transient variable scoped locally to a single function, and self.foo's state will persist across multiple calls to the same method (or even other methods that also reference self.foo).**

Comment: your suspicion was right on. Encountering that problem, combined with your explanation of using `self.` made me understand much better what that actually means and I'll be able to go through and clean that up now, as I did that for absolutely every function in every module I have, except main. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
while self.x < len(self.query_data):
   pass
```

Unlike C or Java, a nice pythonic solution would use enumerate:

```
>>> listy = ['a','b','c']
>>> for idx, val in enumerate(listy):
>>>     print 'listy[{}] is {}'.format(idx, val)
listy[0] is a
listy[1] is b
listy[2] is c
```

Comment: Actually, a "nice pythonic solution" would iterate directly over the values, seeing as how the index is only ever used to access those values.